# Creating a zend project to generate googlecharts

Tags: zend-framework, google-visualization

Hi, I'm working on a `zend project` to generate graphs using the `google charts api` which uses the values from the database it views the tables, year and months from "Jan to Dec" with their values below them. Below are my scripts. Everything works fine but when I click the link to output the graphs: I get my code back..in the form of an array and not a visual chart.

```
['Year', 'Month', ''Value'], ['2008","january,'65], ['2008","february,'56], ['2008","march,'78], ['2008","april,'3], ['2008","may,'67], ['2008","june,'34], ['2008","july,'74], ['2008","august,'85], ['2008","september,'97], ['2008","october,'57], ['2008","november,'58], ['2008","december,'34]
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

```
IndexController.php
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
   {
    $yearlyreport = new Application_Model_DbTable_YearlyReport();
    $this->view->yearlyreport = $yearlyreport->fetchAll();

   }

    public function generategraphAction()
   {
    //$yearlyreport = new Application_Model_DbTable_YearlyReport();
    //$this->view->yearlyreport = $yearlyreport->fetchAll();


    //$this->User();
      //get id param from index.phtml (view)
     $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
     //get model and query by $i
     $yearlyreport = new Application_Model_DbTable_YearlyReport();
     $row = $yearlyreport->getYearlyReport($id);
     //assign data from model to view [EDIT](display.phtml)
     $this->view->yearlyreport = $yearlyreport;

   /*Create a dtring of the form:
    * var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
      ]);
    * 
    */

   $data = "['Year', 'Month', ''Value'],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'january' . ",'" .    $row['January'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'february' . ",'" . $row['February'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'march' . ",'" . $row['March'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'april' . ",'" . $row['April'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'may' . ",'" . $row['May'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'june' . ",'" . $row['June'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'july' . ",'" . $row['July'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'august' . ",'" . $row['August'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'september' . ",'" . $row['September'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'october' . ",'" . $row['October'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'november' . ",'" . $row['November'] . "],
            ['" . $row['year'] . '","' . 'december' . ",'" . $row['December'] . "],";



     $this->view->data = $data;




 }

}
?>

Generategraph.phtml
<?php
echo $this->doctype();
echo $this->data;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = <?php echo $this->data; ?>

    var options = {
      title: 'Generate',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>

 YearlyReport.php "models"
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_YearlyReport extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

 protected $_name = 'yearlyreport';

public function getYearlyReport($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id;
    $row = $this->fetchRow('id =' . $id);
    if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}

         public function generategraph($year, $January, $February, $March, $April, $May, $June, $July, $August, $September, $October, $November, $December )
 {
    $data = array(
    'year' => $year,
    'January' => $January,
    'February' => $February,
    'March' => $March,
    'April' => $April,
    'May' => $May,
    'June' => $June,
    'July' => $July,
    'August' => $August,
    'September' => $September,
    'October' => $October,
    'November' => $November,
    'December' => $December,
    );

    $this->generategraph($data);

 }





}
  index.phtml  
  <?php
$this->title = "YearlyReports";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
?>

  <table>
<tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>February</th>
    <th>March</th>
    <th>April</th>
    <th>May</th>
    <th>June</th>
    <th>July</th>
    <th>August</th>
    <th>September</th>
    <th>October</th>
    <th>November</th>
    <th>December</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach ($this->yearlyreport as $yearly) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->year); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->January); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->February); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->March); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->April); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->May); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->June); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->July); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->August); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->September); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->October); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->November); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($yearly->December); ?></td>

        <td>
              <a href="<?php echo  $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'generategraph', 'id'=>$yearly->id));?>">GenerateGraph</a>
        </td>



        </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `BarChart`, it usually only requires 2 columns of data: the label and the value.

So Change the $data variable to the following:

```
$data = "['Month', 'Value'],
['January'," . $row['January'] . "],
['February'," . $row['February'] . "],
['March'," . $row['March'] . "],
['April'," . $row['April'] . "],
['May'," . $row['May'] . "],
['June'," . $row['June'] . "],
['July'," . $row['July'] . "],
['August'," . $row['August'] . "],
['September'," . $row['September'] . "],
['October'," . $row['October'] . "],
['November'," . $row['November'] . "],
['December'," . $row['December'] . "]";
```